# In SSL trust hierarchies, what is used to sign an intermediate certificate and how does this relate to the root certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm completing an assignment on SSL and I feel I understand the basics of how certs are used with asymmetric and symmetric encryption. But I'm having difficulty understanding some details of how exactly trust hierarchies work.

Specifically, what is used to sign an intermediate certificate? All the guides I've looked at state that the CA root cert is used to sign the intermediate cert. But what exactly does "sign" mean here? In other words, how does a server prove that its intermediate certificate is authenticated by the CA root cert?

My guess is that the public key or signature of the root cert are used when generating the signature of intermediate cert the but I'm not sure if this is accurate.

I would really appreciate any info to improve my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is exactly one intermediate, which is often but not always the case, the intermediate cert is signed by the root in exactly the same way an end-entity cert (for SSL/TLS mostly a server cert) is signed by the intermediate. In both cases this is a shorthand; **signing is actually done using the private key** of an asymmetric keypair, and the cert contains the public key of the same keypair which is used to verify signatures made with the private key. Since the private keys are private and all of us who use the CAs see only their public keys, we focus on that. Thus:

- the server cert is signed using the private key belonging to the intermediate CA; the intermediate cert contains the matching public key. As part of verifying the server cert, the relier (e.g. browser) finds or confirms the intermediate cert using the Isssuer name in the server cert, and uses the public key from the intermediate cert to verify the signature on the server cert; this assures that the server cert was actually issued by the intermediate CA and has not been tampered with.

  According to SSL/TLS standards the server should always send the intermediate cert (or certs, in order) following the server cert in the handshake, although if it fails to do so, some clients may use AIA from the certificate or other heuristic means to obtain the cert, or may have it already cached or even configured.
- the intermediate cert is signed using the private key belonging to the root CA; the root cert contains the matching public key. As part of verifying the intermediate cert, the relier finds the root cert using the Issuer name in the intermediate cert, and uses the public key from the root cert to verify the signature on the intermediate cert; this assures that the intermediate cert was actually issued by the root CA and has not been tampered with.

  The root cert normally must (already) be in the relier's local 'trust store' and the server does not need to send it; normally the trust store is provided either by the browser developer (Firefox) or by the OS/platform developer (IE/Edge, Chrome, Safari).

Notice the close parallel between these two statements with the (notable) exception of how the relier finds the parent cert. Also note that validating a server cert chain for an SSL/TLS connection involves much more than just verifying the signatures, although verifying the signatures is a critical part and without it the other validation criteria could not be assured.

One intermediate CA, and intermediate cert, will generally be used by a large number (thousands to millions) of server certs and servers. The server isn't responsible for 'proving' anything about the intermediate cert, only passing it on to the client, which validates the entire chain.

Cross-stack see also 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity
which has a nice graphic of this relationship.

Comment: Very helpful and concise. I finally get it now. Thanks :)